# Is it possible to get the number of call in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

Is it possible to get the number of invocation of mocked method in Spock? I want to test if the method is called specific number of times, but every second returned value should be different. Pseudo code below should illustrate more specific what I want:

```
void "My idea of a test" {
    when:
       ...
    then:
        10 * someService(_) >> {
             return theNumberOfTheCall % 2 ? SOME_VALUE : null // theNumberOfTheCall should illustrate my purpose
        }
// so the service will return [null, SOME_VALUE, null, SOME_VALUE, null ...]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using chaining:

```
10 * someService(_) >>> (1..10).collect {
       it % 2 ? SOME_VALUE : null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spock by itself does not pass an number of invocation to mocked method, but you utilize `AtomicInteger` to increase counter defined in your test method. Consider following simple example:

```
import spock.lang.Specification    
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

class InvocationCounterSpec extends Specification {

    def "should return different value depending on invocation counter"() {
        setup:
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0)
        final SomeService someService = Mock(SomeService)
        final SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(someService)

        when:
        someClass.run()

        then:
        10 * someService.someMethod() >> {
            return counter.getAndIncrement() % 2 ? "SOME_VALUE" : null
        }

    }

    static interface SomeService {
        def someMethod()
    }

    static class SomeClass {
        private final SomeService someService

        SomeClass(SomeService someService) {
            this.someService = someService
        }

        void run() {
            (0..<10).each {
                def value = someService.someMethod()
                println "someService.someMethod() returned ${value}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example `someClass.run()` method invokes mocked `someService.someMethod()` 10 times. We stub `someService.someMethod()` returned value using a counter that calculates invocation number for us. If you run this test you will see following output:

```
someService.someMethod() returned null
someService.someMethod() returned SOME_VALUE
someService.someMethod() returned null
someService.someMethod() returned SOME_VALUE
someService.someMethod() returned null
someService.someMethod() returned SOME_VALUE
someService.someMethod() returned null
someService.someMethod() returned SOME_VALUE
someService.someMethod() returned null
someService.someMethod() returned SOME_VALUE
```

Hope it helps.